# How do I pull large number of multiple rows from one table?

Tags: php, mysql, database

This is an expansion of my original question located here:
[How do I pull all rows from a table with one unique field and specific values for another field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19301885/how-do-i-pull-all-rows-from-a-table-with-one-unique-field-and-specific-values-fo)

I have a table with two fields: user_id and skill_id.

I want to pull out all rows that have a skill_id of a certain number but I have a large number of skill_id's to search for (~30). I was using the self-join suggestion presented in the question linked above but with so many skills to look for, that query is proving extremely slow.

How can I look for a large number of skill_ids without bogging down the query?

EDIT:

Here's an example of what I'm looking for. Using the table below, I want to pull out all rows of users that have skill_id of 10 AND 11 AND 12, etc. (except I'd be looking for more like 30 skills at a time).

```
TABLE

user_id   |  skill_id
=====================
1         |    10
1         |    11
1         |    12
1         |    13
2         |    10
2         |    12
2         |    13
3         |    15
3         |    16
4         |    10
5         |    45
5         |    46
```

Comment: the question is a bit confusing... it would help greatly if you can provide some sample data.. and what you're looking for in the output.

Comment: See my edit, I just added some more info and an example table.

Comment: `select user_id from table  where skill_id IN (10,11,12...)` make suer skill_is is indexed

Comment: @Dagon - I tried that but that looks for 10 OR 11 OR 12.  I need AND - all rows that have skill_id 10 AND 11 AND 12, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question well, below query might help you. Assuming `(user_id, skill_id)` is UNIQUE or PK.

```
SELECT user_id
FROM tab
WHERE skill_id IN (30 entries)
GROUP BY user_id
HAVING SUM(skill_id IN (30 entries)) = 30;
```

You can test here. http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f73dfe/1/0

Comment: Not bullet proof but should work if user_id/skill_id pair is unique.

Answer (score 0):

```
select user_id 
from table 
where skill_id IN (10,11,12...)
```

make suer skill_is is indexed

Comment: I tried that but that looks for 10 OR 11 OR 12. I need AND - all rows that have skill_id 10 AND 11 AND 12, etc.